# Sufficient condition for a indefinite integral to be an elementary function

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

I would like to find a sufficient condition on two polynomials $P(s)$ and $Q(s)$, such that the function $s \mapsto Q(s)e^{P(s)} $ has a primitive integral of the form $s \mapsto R(s)e^{P(s)} $ (with $R(s)$ a polynomial in $\mathbb R[s]$).

For instance I believe that $e^{s^2}(a_3 s^3+a_2 s^2+a_1 s+a_0)$ has a primitive integral of the form $s \mapsto R(s)e^{s^2} $ if $a_2 = 2a_0$. But what would be the sufficient condition in a general case ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can't you take $R(s)$ general and differentiate $R(s)e^{s^2}$ to see what comes out?

Comment: Taking $R(s)$ general and differentiate $R(s)e^{P(s)}$ would help me to find a condition $C_2(P,Q)$ on $P(s)$ and $Q(s)$, such that « if $s \mapsto R(s)e^{P(s)} $ is an indefinite integral of $s \mapsto Q(s)e^{P(s)} $, then $C_2(P,Q)$ ».    But I would like to find a condition $C_1(P,Q)$ on $P(s)$ and $Q(s)$, such that « if $C_1(P,Q)$, then $s \mapsto R(s)e^{P(s)} $ is an indefinite integral of $s \mapsto Q(s)e^{P(s)} $ ».

Comment: I don't think you have actually tried to do what I said. Let $$F(s)=(a_0+a_1s+a_2s^2+\cdots+a_ns^n)e^{s^2}$$ Then $$F'(s)=(a_1+(2a_2+2a_0)s+(3a_3+2a_1)s^2+\cdots+2a_{n-1}s^n+2a_ns^{n+1})e^{s^2}$$. For this to have the form  $(b_0+b_1s+b_2s^2+b_3s^3)e^{s^2}$, the necessary and sufficient conditions are $n=2$, $b_3=2a_2$, $b_2=2a_1$, $b_1=2a_2+2a_0$, and $b_0=a_1$.